# How do I stop the moving of a button while clicking another?

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

The following code contains 2 buttons and their respective drop-down contents.
When I click the first button, the other moves by itself. How do I stop this from happening?

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block")
      content.style.display = "none";
    else
      content.style.display = "block";
  });
}
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="button" style="position: static; left: 100;">For Copper Rollers</button>
<div class="content" style=" width: 48%; background-color: lightblue; padding: 10px; border-radius: 10px; margin-right: 5px; ">
</div>
<button class="button" type="button" style="position: static; left: 175px; ">For Rubber Rollers</button>
<div class="content" style="margin-left:50%; float: left; width: 48%; background-color: lightblue; padding: 10px; border-radius: 10px;">
</div>
```

Comment: Are the `content` divs all to appear at the same horizontal offset (ie: left:50% as is) or relative to their parent button?

Comment: On the same horizontal offset.

Comment: does that mean that all the content divs are to be aligned under each other to one side of the page as the 1st one ?

Comment: The first content div to be the first half of the page and the next adjacent to it at the 2nd half. (next to each other)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign `position:absolute` you can do some rudimentary calculations in Javascript to determine the position the `content` should appear at. Is this more or less the desired effect?

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(( bttn, index )=>bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  
  // get the bounding box for the button so we can
  // get a suitable height offset for content
  let bb=this.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  // find the content and toggle display state
  let div=this.nextElementSibling;
      div.style.display=div.style.display=='block' ? 'none' : 'block';
  
  // find the current style properties for the content
  let style=getComputedStyle( div );
  let bbd=div.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  // calculate x / y positions for content 
  let x=( Math.ceil( bbd.width ) + parseInt( style.paddingLeft ) - parseInt( style.marginLeft ) ) * index;
  let y=Math.ceil( bb.height ) + Math.ceil( bb.bottom );
  
  // apply those positions to the content
  div.style.top=`${y}px`;
  div.style.left=`${x}px`;
  
  // identify content by parent
  div.textContent=this.textContent.replace('For ','');
}));
```

```css
body{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
}
button.button{
  padding:0.25rem;
}

/*
  assign the absolute position
  to the content divs but let
  javascript calculate x/y positions.
*/
.content {
  position:absolute;
  display: none;
  width: calc( 50% - 3rem );
  background-color:lightblue;
  padding:1rem;
  border-radius:10px;
  border:1px solid grey;
  float:none;
  clear:none;
  margin:0 0.25rem;
}


.content:first-of-type{
  background:pink;
}
.active{
  color:green
}
```

```html
<!-- 
  let css do the styling and positioning as `inline` styles
  make updating a pain in the proverbial
-->
<button type="button" class="button">For Copper Rollers</button>
<div class="content"></div>

<button class="button" type="button">For Rubber Rollers</button>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with making the dropdown content have a `position: asolute` (css), that way it won't affect any other elements on the page.

PS: make sure to keep accessibility in mind when making dropdowns, your current snippet unfortunately isn't.

Comment: I tried but its still not working.